# Android - Add bottom navigation view dynamically

Tags: android, menu, bottomnavigationview

I try to add a bottom navigation view dynamically. I know that I add a navigation view inside activity's xml file.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
   android:id="@+id/navigation"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   design:menu="@menu/items" />
```

I don't want to create a item xml file. I used below code to create navigation bar.

```
    bottomNavigationView = new BottomNavigationView(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    bottomNavigationView.setLayoutParams(params);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewLayout);
    layout.addView(bottomNavigationView);

    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    menu.add(0, i, Menu.NONE, "TEXT");
```

menu.add throws an error.

> android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.size()' on a null object reference

How can I add a navigation view dynamically?

Comment: what is the version of your support library?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

Comment: Update your support library and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug of `BottomNavigationView`.

Here is the bug reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37124043

This has been fixed in support library `25.0.1`. Update your `support library` and try again.

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

try to do this

```
bottomNavigationView = new BottomNavigationView(ActivityName.this);
```

or

```
bottomNavigationView = new BottomNavigationView(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library. This error is occured BottomNavigationView constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can define menu xml and inflate it calling inflateMenu method on BottomNavigationView object.

If you need to add any additional menu items, you can do by getting menu object and adding items to menu object.

Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();

Comment: Yes, I know. But I try to create without menu xml file. Is is possible?

Comment: I tried and could not reproduce the issue of Menu object being null.

Comment: My problem is not about xml file. I don't want to create a xml under res/menu. I try to create 'new BottomNavigationView()' dynamically and add to layout.

Comment: Yes, I was able to create BottomNavigationView pragmatically without any issue using latest versions.